# Why don't the size of variables don't change with platform of JVM(64 bit or 32 bit) we are using?

Tags: java, jvm

I have encountered a problem:
All the variables that we declare(int, float, char double) have the same memory size,
even though, the JVM platform differs(32 bit or 64 bit)
int occupies 4 bytes
float 4 bytes
char 2 bytes
What is the reason ??

Comment: Because it is defined not to change.

Comment: Because the specification says so.

Answer (score 4):

In Java the Java Virtual Machine specification explicitly says that these types are those sizes. See [2.3. Primitive Types and Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.3):

> The integral types are:
>
> - `byte`, whose values are 8-bit signed two's-complement integers, and whose default value is zero
> - `short`, whose values are 16-bit signed two's-complement integers, and whose default value is zero
> - `int`, whose values are 32-bit signed two's-complement integers, and whose default value is zero
> - `long`, whose values are 64-bit signed two's-complement integers, and whose default value is zero
> - `char`, whose values are 16-bit unsigned integers representing Unicode code points in the Basic Multilingual Plane, encoded with UTF-16, and whose default value is the null code point (`'\u0000'`)
>
> The floating-point types are:
>
> - `float`, whose values are elements of the float value set or, where supported, the float-extended-exponent value set, and whose default value is positive zero
> - `double`, whose values are elements of the double value set or, where supported, the double-extended-exponent value set, and whose default value is positive zero
>
> The values of the `boolean` type encode the truth values true and false, and the default value is false.

And rightly so, the platform dependent sizes of some language are really annoying, and it makes it hard to reason and work with it. The Java virtual machine is an abstract machine that works the same independent of the underlying physical hardware. Therefor the sizes are fixed by specification. This simplifies developing platform independent software, and it is one of the reasons that Sun originally marketed Java as ["write once, run anywhere"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once,_run_anywhere).

Answer (score 3):

Java is supposed to be cross platform language. I.e, the code you write once should work on all platforms and behave the same. That's why the primitive type lengths are always the same across all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Basically JVM is made according to it such that all data type's specification doesn't change.
JVM is made for different machine uniquely. This is made for making platform independent codes.[For JVM information](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/jvm3.html)